# QUnit test error with IE (Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

Hy i wrote some QUnit test's for an old JS-File (an specific Date-calculation-JS).

**Question:**

It works very well on Firefox and Chrome but **i got this Error on IE**:

```
Died on test #1 undefined: Der Wert der Eigenschaft "jQuery" ist Null
oder undefiniert, kein Function-Objekt
```

and on IE8:

```
Died on test #1 undefined: Object expected
```

**Specs:**

*You can take a look at my [Javascript Code](http://www.parsdorf-express.de/assets/js/departureCalculation.js).

I used [this](https://qunitjs.com/) minimal QUnit HTML pattern.

JQuery version: 2.1.3

QUnit version: 1.17.1*

Answer (score 0):

*At first, i tried to change "$" with "jQuery", but this error still exists.*

In my case, i solved this issue for **IE >= 9** by adding the following meta-Tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

IE8 won't work with jQuery version 2.x.x. 
You only have to change your JQuery-Version, e.g. to 'jquery-1.11.2.min.js'.